# Emacs org-mode export markdown

Tags: emacs, markdown, org-mode, emacs24

I have some weird behavior, I don't actually know if it's a bug or something else.
When I do `C-c C-e` the option to convert to markdown doesn't appear. Nonetheless I can type the option `M-x org-md-export-as-markdown` and after I do that, the option export to markdown appears in the `C-c C-e` menu.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you are using Org-mode version 8.0 or later (check with `M-x org-version`), the export framework is [broken up into several libraries](http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/ox-overview.html) that are not necessarily loaded by default.

Something like this in your Emacs configuration can load the Markdown exporter automatically with Org-mode:

```
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(require 'ox-md nil t))
```

Answer (score 2):

After emacs 25,you just need add a line in your emacs configuration file: .emacs

```
(require 'ox-md nil t)
```

Comment: You could probably do the same thing in `emacs24`, but `eval-after-load` is used so it can be loaded only after `org-mode` is loaded.

Comment: … or run `(require 'ox-md nil t)` in `M-:` when emacs is already running.

Answer (score 2):

M-x customize-variable <Ret> org-export-backends <Ret>

check option 'md', then save.

Comment: Nice.  This is the easiest and it shows you other available exporters.