# Org mode export options, such as ODT, beamer

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using emacs on two different machines and despite having the same init.el file and the same package libraries, they seem to have different sets of packages installed, with a lot of different behavior.  The place I'm noticing this most is in my org mode export options.

Both machines have org version 2012422 installed.

On one (good, new) machine, I can export safely to ODT for example.

```
[t]   insert the export option template
[v]   limit export to visible part of outline tree
[1]   switch buffer/subtree
[SPC] pubish enclosing subtree (with LaTeX_CLASS or EXPORT_FILE_NAME prop)

[a/n/u] export as ASCII/Latin-1/UTF-8   [A/N/U] to temporary buffer

[h] export as HTML     [H] to temporary buffer   [R] export region
[b] export as HTML and open in browser

[l] export as LaTeX    [L] to temporary buffer
[p] export as LaTeX and process to PDF           [d] ... and open PDF file

[D] export as DocBook  [V] export as DocBook, process to PDF, and open

[o] export as OpenDocument Text                  [O] ... and open

[j] export as TaskJuggler                        [J] ... and open

[m] export as Freemind mind map
[x] export as XOXO
[g] export using Wes Hardaker's generic exporter

[i] export current file as iCalendar file
[I] export all agenda files as iCalendar files   [c] ...as one combined file

[F] publish current file           [P] publish current projects
[X] publish a project...           [E] publish every projects
```

(Sorry if there are any errors above: this is all typed out by hand, by the way.  I cannot actually select the option buffer that pops up when I type C-c C-e; the bottom buffer just starts recording my attempts to switch buffers and even my mouse clicks, which is frustrating.)

On the other machine, which has an older emacs installation, but same org version, I have the following options...

```
[C-b] Body only:    Off       [C-v] Visible only:     Off
[C-s] Export scope: Buffer    [C-f] Force publishing: Off
[C-a] Async export: Off

[c] Export to iCalendar
    [f] Current file          [a] All agenda files
    [c] Combine all agenda files

[h] Export to HTML
    [H] As HTML buffer        [h] As HTML file
    [o] As HTML file and open

[l] Export to LaTeX
    [L] As LaTeX buffer       [l] As LaTeX file
    [p] As PDF file           [o] As PDF file and open

[t] Export to Plain Text
    [A] As ASCII buffer       [a] As ASCII file
    [L] As Latin1 buffer      [l] As Latin1 file
    [U} As UTF-8 buffer       [u] As UTF-8 file

[P] Publish
    [f] Current file          [p] Current project
    [x] Choose project        [a] All Projects

[&] Export stack              [#] Insert template
[q] Exit
```

I prefer the organization of the latter, but it lacks the export features the first one has, such as ODT which I use regularly.

Anyway, they are both in theory using the standard, installed base org package which is kept updated on both machines.  What could be causing such disparity in export options?  Does anyone familiar with org mode exports recognize the different menu styles enough to give some pointers?

Comment: Can you manually `M-x org-odt-export-to-odt` in the second example? Also, please use `M-x org-version` to confirm that you have identical versions of Org-mode.

Comment: When I do the manual export, I get... `OpenDocument export failed: wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

Comment: Machine 1 has org... `7.9.3f (... /usr/share/emacs/24.3/list/org)`
Machine 2 has org... `8.2.6 (... /home/mittenchops/.emacs.d/elpa/org-*)`
Huh, OK, that's weird.  They had the same number in the `M-x list-packages`.  This is also weird because machine 1 seems to give me more features than machine 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Chris' advice above, I saw the answer was to do the update/installation step on machine 2 from [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html).

So, I had to add the `~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-*` to my load path, a la:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/path/to/orgdir/lisp")
```

Now, I can export to ODF.

Comment: The likely reason that your Org 7.x offers more options than Org 8.x is that the new version [introduced a modular export framework](http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/ox-overview.html), and not all backends are enabled by default. You may be interested in my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988092/emacs-org-mode-export-markdown/22990257) about enabling Markdown export out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

#### For org-mode version 8.x

I added the below snippet to my `init.el` and now I see the option to export to ODT format when I do `C-c C-e` in `org-mode`.

```
;; Enable org export to odt (OpenDocument Text)
;; It is disabled by default in org 8.x
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(require 'ox-odt nil t))
```